# CnosDB Custom Function Issue

Tags: cnosdb

MySQL:

````
CREATE FUNCTION hello_world(name VARCHAR(50))
RETURNS VARCHAR(50)
BEGIN
    RETURN CONCAT('Hello, ', name, '!');
END
```
SELECT hello_world('Test');
````

How can I define custom functions and achieve similar functionality in CnosDB? I have encountered such a requirement while using CnosDB, and I do not know how to solve it.